# How to track websites with my own code for Affiliate Network

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, architecture, backend

I am working on an affiliate network project. Can you please share your thoughts that how can I track any website by writing my own code? Just like Google Tag Manager, Facebook Pixel and Clickbank.

I want to know how these codes work and what's the algorithm in the backend.

Comment: Can you be a bot more specific?  "Track any website" is a bit vague.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.